# how do I dynamically redirect specific subdirectories based on URL pattern?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Spent hours searching for a solution, but I know next to nothing about htaccess and redirections.

My question is: How do I redirect specific portions of a URL, and ignore others?

e.g. `http://www.example.com/foo` redirects to `http://www.example.com/`
and `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` remains as-is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /foo http://www.example.com
```

For more information about .htaccess check out [this turorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with following

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds, as If you need some kind of generalized solution. If this is the case, you can use `mod_rewrite` for this, provided the module is installed and enabled for your apache or you have access to apache yourself.

This is much more powerful than simple redirects, but it is also much easier to shoot yourself in the foot.

It works with Conditions and Rules for rewriting URLs based on regular expressions.

To redirect only (and exactly) /foo you would define:

```
 RewriteRule ^/foo$        http://www.example.com
```

This would keep **anything** below foo untouched, even /foo/index.html.

To redirect anything below foo, that does not contain the subdirectory bar or some other subdirectories it would look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/foo/(bar|whatever|subdirectories)/
RewriteRule ^/foo(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1      [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` checks if the specified directories cannot be found in the `REQUEST_URI` and applies a general redirect of anything below foo, if this is the case; the `$1` contains what is captured by the regular expression inside the parentheses `(.*)`.

The trailing par `[R=301,L]` in the rule makes it behave like a redirect with the given HTTP return code 301 and makes it the last (`L`) redirect rule applied - otherwise applying further rules could create some different result.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Surprising to see so many incorrect answer here. You just need precise regex to target `/foo` here with optional trailing slash.

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/foo/?$ /
```